# Replace an object in a Set

Tags: flutter, dart

It seems to be easy to do, just can't understand how.
I want to replace an object contained in a `Set` of objects. What's the way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you just remove your object and add the new one?

Comment: @AmazingBite Performance wise I don't think it's the best solution

Comment: Don't presume. Simpler things are often the best ones. I'd go as said by @AmazingBite => remove and add.

Comment: @Muldec Ok then, thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your understanding of how objects are stored in a `Set` might not be completely accurate.

The `Set` itself only holds references to objects. If you remove that reference and the object is not referenced anywhere else, the garbage collector will drop that object and remove it from memory.

You cannot "replace" an object because the `Set` only holds a reference to your object.
The only way you can remove one object and insert another is the following:

```dart
set.remove(object);
set.add(anotherObject);
```

Comment: Thank you man, shame that I had to make such a big problem of it.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no way in a `Set` to replace a reference to an object with a reference to a different object. Using the two operations of `remove()` followed by `add()` should suffice for most purposes, however doing so requires the object hash and lookup to occur twice instead of once.

The scenario in which `Set` replacement is potentially useful is when it involves a type for which differing objects may be considered equal (as given by its implementation of `operator==` and `hashCode`). In other words, the situation of interest is likely not

```
set.remove(object);
set.add(anotherObject);
```

but is rather

```
set.remove(anotherObject);
set.add(anotherObject);
```

where the set may contain an existing reference to a different object `object` such that `anotherObject == object` is `true`.

If replacement is somehow important, use of a `Map` with identical keys and values can be considered in place of a `Set`, since `Map`s do allow replacement. for example:

```
  final map = <Object, Object>{};
  final object = Object();
  map[object] = object;
```

Additionally, it may also be worth mentioning that this is possible to achieve using a `Set` and introducing a layer of indirection:

```
class Indirect<T> {
  T value;
  
  Indirect(this.value);
  
  @override
  bool operator==(Object other) => value == other;
  
  @override
  int get hashCode => value.hashCode;
}

void main() {
  final aset = <Indirect<Object>>{};
  final object = Object();
  final indirect = aset.lookup(object) ?? Indirect(object);
  aset.add(indirect);
  indirect.value = object;
}
```

This works because once added to the set, the `Indirect` never needs to be replaced--instead, the `Indirect`'s `value` is simply overwritten as needed. And, crucially, an `Indirect` has the same hash and equality as the `value` it represents. However, in practice, there isn't a compelling motivation to use this approach, as it offers no advantages (still two hashes and lookups), yet introduces unnecessary complexity.

Either way, be cautious of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).